# How to re-project shapefiles?

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, ogr2ogr

I wanted to re-project a QGIS project, but there is no such option. When searching for an answer I see `ogr2ogr` suggested for this task, by re-projecting each vector layer (shapefile in this example). However I don't get expected result:

```
C:\temp>ogrinfo -al -so misc.shp
INFO: Open of `misc.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: misc
Geometry: Line String
Feature Count: 10
Extent: (21.267388, 42.015857) - (21.270225, 42.017470)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["MGI_Balkans_zone_7_deprecated",
    GEOGCS["GCS_MGI",
        DATUM["Militar_Geographische_Institute",
            SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",21],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",7500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
id: Integer (10.0)

C:\temp>ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 misc_re.shp misc.shp

C:\temp>ogrinfo -al -so misc_re.shp
INFO: Open of `misc_re.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: misc_re
Geometry: Line String
Feature Count: 10
Extent: (-34.004490, 0.000230) - (-34.004490, 0.000230)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS_84",6378137,298.257223563]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
id: Integer (10.0)
```

So new file has changed geographic coordinate system, but it's not projected.
How to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to reproject a shapefile? A project file has a `.qqs` ending, a shapefile ends with `.shp`. I don't think you can re-project a project file but I could be wrong.

Comment: I assume you already know the "on the fly" reprojection in QGIS that enables reprojecting any vector layer.

Comment: @steko: If "on the fly" is what is answered by djq, yes I already knew that.

Comment: No, that is another way and it will permanently change the data. On the fly reprojection is only defined in the QGIS project and will affect how the layers are visualized but not touch the underlying files.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about that, and Googling it showed me what you meant. It's exactly what I needed. If you could have only posted your last comment yesterday... I did lot of typing to get there ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you want to reproject a shapefile, one way within `QGIS` is to load the file, `right-click` on the layer, select `Save As…`, and then the following window appears:

[image]

If you click `browse` beside `CRS` you can choose a new projection to save your file in.

EDIT:

To reproject all shapfiles in the one folder, something like this could work:

```
set "str1=_projected"
for %f in (E:\data\*.shp) do ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 %str1%"misc_re.shp %f
```

(I haven't tested this and am unfamiliar with [string concatenation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) on windows, nor am I solving the ogr2ogr issue - but this code snippet loops through a folder and runs something on each file.)

Comment: Yes that's great, but I would have to do that for every layer, which is time consuming. By using command line I was hoping to re-project all shapefiles at once (with for loop)

Comment: Are all the shapefiles in the one folder?

Comment: Yes, they are in same folder

Comment: thanks for your effort, but did you actually read my question?

Comment: yes... you can't reproject a qgis project file which is why I gave my first answer. Then I realized you wanted to reproject the shapefiles in bulk. One way of doing this is to loop through all the files in a folder using the command line with ogr (another would be to see if you can pass ogr a folder of shapefiles).

Comment: But it just changes coordinate system without re-projecting. That's why I asked this question. Please see the code box in my question more closely

Comment: What do you want to project it to? You chose `EPSG:4326` which converted the shapefile from the previous projection to `WGS_84`

Comment: But it's not projected. `PROJCS` dictionary is not present in metadata and coordinates are wrong. See the coordinates (Extent) in source file and then in file output by ogr2ogr.

Comment: Can you try something like `EPSG:900913` as a test? Moving between lat/long projection systems is still re-projecting; WGS84 is a lat/long system.

Comment: With EPSG:900913 instead EPSG:4326 I get `"PROJCS["Google_Maps_Global_Mercator"...` but coordinates are totally off :`Extent: (-3785362.530285, 25.607240) - (-3785362.528919, 25.608223)`

Comment: I don't know your dataset or the google values well enough to judge, but as a reference a point in Dublin, Ireland using EPSG:900913 is `-788694.0, 6956099.0`. These coordinates are not lat/lng they are x/y in meters.

Comment: I tried different projections and they all output very different values for coordinates. I'll ask at gdal mailing list, and post results if I get answer. Thanks for your time

Comment: This is probably a more appropriate forum than GDAL, it is just a matter of sorting out the terminology.   One point to clarify, are you trying to change the underlying data (permanent) or change what you see in the map canvas (temporary)?

Comment: I was trying to overlay vector layer from one projection (epsg:31277) to another (epsg:4326). However I did not understood this well, as now I know that I don't need re-projection (changing the shapefile data) but just change to shapefile projection file (.prj) by using `-a_srs` instead `-t_srs`. Issue why EPSG:4326 SRS that didn't had projection, was because it's WGS84 geographic coordinate system, so it doesn't need projection, as was shown to me by others.