# How to make a spatially map using interpolation method?

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I have a .csv file which has PH value of groundwater for the couple of locations in state of WEST BENGAL (India). First I uploaded the .csv file data using "Add Delimited Text Layer" and make a Continuous distribution raster layer which have five classes and look like this:

[image]

Now I want to distribute these PH values of five classes in the Polygon shapefile of West Bengal state.  But when I import Polygon shapefile of West Bengal then the coordinates do not match with the raster field.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Open the properties of the raster.  Note the spatial reference (coordinate system and projection).

Now open the properties of the shapefile.  Note the spatial reference.

You've noticed they are different.

You'll need to reproject the shapefile into the spatial reference (coordinate system and projection) of the raster.

To do this, click on the shapefile in the table of contents.  Right click > select 'save as'.  Set the spatial reference the same as the spatial reference of the raster.

See the answer on this post: [How to re-project shapefiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43848/how-to-re-project-shapefiles)